# springboot - Json object return invalid

Tags: spring-boot

Currently, I am using rest template to get data from external api in getter method. While printing in console log, valid json format is coming. But, through postman output, invalid json output is coming (with \").  Pls suggest.

```
public class Product {

@Id
public Integer id;
private String name;

public Product() {
        }

public Product(Integer id, String name) {
    this.id = id;
    this.name = name;
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    final String uri = "http://example.com/";
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri + this.getId(), String.class);
    System.out.println(result);
    return result;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
  }
```

---

```
//console.log (example)

{"product":{"rating_and_review_reviews":{"hasErrors":false,"offset":0,
"totalResults":0,"locale":"en_US","limit":10,"duration":1,"result":
[]},"question_answer_statistics"
```

---

```
// POSTMAN - HTTP GET (coming with \)
{
"id": 1,
"name": "{\"product\":{\"rating\":{\"hasErrors\":false,\"offset\":0,
\"totalResults\":0,\"locale\":\"en_US\",\"limit\":10,
\"duration\":1,\"result\":[]}
```

Comment: What is the `content-type` response header you are getting? Is it `application/json`?

Comment: Yes Mohamed, 'content-type = application/json'

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of the postman response with response headers?

Comment: ![image](https://ibb.co/f4EPyG)

Comment: I was asking about the Response Headers. What you have shown be is the request headers. Response headers is in the tab along with Body, Cookies ...

Comment: ok, got it... I am seeing like below 

    content-type →application/hal+json;charset=UTF-8
    date →Sun, 12 Nov 2017 04:47:00 GMT
    transfer-encoding →chunked

Comment: If you can set the content type while sending the response from the server to `application/json` you should be able to see properly formatted resposne in Postman